# vue3 async component with multi modules

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In my project, I want to load the component as an async component. I found that I can use "defineAsyncComponent", but it just load default module. Is it possible to load other module? for example, async load `import {ArrowLeftOutlined, UploadOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons-vue'` ?

```
const asyncBbox = defineAsyncComponent({
    loader: () => new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (componentName)
            resolve(import('./example-label-component'));
        resolve({
            template: '<div>Undefined Component</div>'
        })
    }),
    timeout: 3000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to load any component you want by declaring it as a variable like this, as long as it is a Vue component:

```js
const myCustomComponent = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/ant-design/icons/ArrowLeftOutlined.vue'))
```